# Migration with SQL sequence is not applied in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the current migration

```
class CreateSlugSequence < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE SEQUENCE slug_sequence
    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute <<-SQL
      DROP SEQUENCE slug_sequence
    SQL
  end
end
```

I run rails db:migrate

Enter rails c (development mode)

Run ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("select nextval('slug_sequence')")[0]['nextval']

And get the expected value

But if I enter rails c in test mode, for some reason, the sequence table does not exist

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "slug_sequence" does not exist
```

I ran `ActiveRecord::Migrator.current_version`, to check what was the last migration applied and it returns the latest version.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Perhaps `RAILS_ENV=test rails db:migrate`

Comment: Yes I did it, that's why i checked the migration version present

Comment: Have you dropped test environment and recreate then reran?

Comment: @Austio I ran rails db:drop, rails db:create and rails db:migrate which applies changes to development and test (At least the terminal logs suggest so). Apparently, it is not that simple, lol... I ran the above commands with the RAILS_ENV=test prefix and it solved it

Comment: @Austio Want the question rewards? Or should I answer my own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommended dropping the test db and recreating it.  Although these *should* remain in sync they sometimes do not and you have to do manual steps to get them together.

`RAILS_ENV=test rake db:reset`

Weird that it is not working with that, would be interesting to drop a pry debugger in that task and see what is going on. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L122

Manual steps

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I tried `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:reset` and it doesnt work. The only way, I managed to make it work is literally do what reset does but in seperated commands. `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop` then `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create` then `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate`

Comment: Whats the difference between line 122 and line 185(At https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake)? Dont they represent the same command?

Comment: Apparently, `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:reset` doesn't do the same as `RAILS_ENV=test rails db:reset`

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to fix `rails db:reset` command, you just need to add line `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` in your `application.rb` so info about sequence will be stored in `structure.sql`. Please take a look that with default schema dump `:ruby` info about seqeunce is not stored in `schema.rb` file.

**Important**: make sure to firstly create `structure.sql` with `rails db:migrate` and then run `rails db:reset`. After just `rails db:migrate` I'm still getting the error you want to fix.