# Migration not executed from rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I created the following migration script (using `bundle exec rails generate migration CreateSequenceStudentId`):

```
class CreateSequenceStudentId < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    # Based on: https://schmijos.medium.com/execute-sql-in-rails-migrations-cdb26f51c683
    execute 'CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS student_id;'
  end
end
```

Then executed `bundle exec rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` and it completed. I can access the sequence using `psql student_test -c"select nextval('student_id')"`. Running `psql student_test -c"select * from schema_migrations sm"` lists `20201122013457` at the very last. No problems so far.

I then wrote the following spec to access the sequence:

```
sql = "select nextval('student_id')"
p Student.connection.select_all(sql)
```

And it failed:

```
# --- Caused by: ---
# PG::UndefinedTable:
#   ERROR:  relation "student_id" does not exist
#   LINE 1: select nextval('student_id')
```

And I executed `psql student_test -c"select nextval('student_id')"` one more time and got:

```
ERROR:  relation "student_id" does not exist
LINE 1: select nextval('student_id')
```

`bundle exec rails db:migrate:status RAILS_ENV=test` gives:

```
 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
...
   up     20201122013457  Create sequence student
```

So it indicates the migration executed successfully.

`psql student_test -c"select * from schema_migrations sm"` gives:

```
    version
----------------
 20201122013457
 20191209013052
 20191220005953
 20191225001051
 20191225001255
 20191225001458
 ...
```

The new script was executed first. This smells fishy.

Sounds like the migration ran successfully when using `db:migrate` but not when running rspec. Appreciate any pointers on what I could be doing wrong.

PS: Based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157013/activerecord-migration-not-executing), I have checked if the script name is unique and it is.

Comment: Did you try `rails db:reset` if you are not afraid to lose your local data?

Comment: Running reset does re-create the sequence. The issue is just when running RSpec.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix your issue by running exact below commands. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53377739/5841310).

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate
```

**UPDATE:**

I found also the way to fix `rails db:reset` command, you just need to add line `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` in your `application.rb` so info about sequence will be stored in `structure.sql`. Please take a look that with default schema dump `:ruby` info about seqeunce is not stored in `schema.rb` file.

**Important**: make sure to firstly create `structure.sql` with `rails db:migrate` and then run `rails db:reset`. After just `rails db:migrate` I'm still getting the error you want to fix.